# What is the equivalent of "integer" from java in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, integer

I have this in java:

```
int minimo = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

how would it look in javascript? Is there an equivalent of n"integer" in javascript?

```
var minimo = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has only one number type `Number`. It automatically switches between floats and integers as needed.

Use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` to get the max **integer** value and `Number.MAX_VALUE` to get the max **float** value.

For me these are `9007199254740991` and `1.7976931348623157e+308`